# Multiple return values, just one 'if' checking functions return

Tags: python, multiple-return-values

What return value(s) does Python check when a function returns multiple values,
but there is only one 'if' checking the function's result?

Thank you for your time.

```
def func1(args):
    return pass, data

def func2
   if func1(args):
       ...
   else 
       raise Exception ...
```

Comment: You can't return `pass` from a function.

Comment: Besides what @yudhiesh correctly stated, when you return multiple values, Python interprets it as a tuple. So it will be `True` whenever a tuple would evaluate as `True`. If a tuple has elements, it will evaluate as `True`.

Comment: You aren't actually returning multiple values; you're returning a tuple, which happens to contain two values.  A tuple is "truthy" if it has a non-zero number of elements, the values of those elements are not relevant.

Comment: If you're returning two values then it's a tuple of length 2, which is truthy, because nonempty things are truthy. (NB they don't "evaluate to True" as several people are saying.)

Comment: @khelwood they do evaluate to True, in boolean context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return multiple values, you're actually returning a tuple containing each of those values.

Your *if* test will return True regardless of the values (even if they are both None)

Comment: Thanks.  Would the if be true if func1 returned '()', an empty tuple?  It does not in the test code I ran.

Comment: No. An empty tuple, list, dictionary or string would return False

Answer (score 5):

`return a, b` would return a tuple. The `if` statement will always evaluate, since non-empty tuples evaluate to `True`.